# Upgrade to magento 2.1 (not a rc)

Tags: magento2, upgrade

This notification from today:

New Community Edition 2.0.x Patch (MDVA-532) Enables Upgrades to Magento 2.1 – June 22, 2016
A new patch, MDVA-532, enables merchants using Magento Community Edition 2.0.x to upgrade to Magento 2.1 Community Edition Release Candidates or GA software. More information about the patch and important instructions for command-line upgrades to Magento 2.1 when sample data is installed are available in a technical bulletin posted at http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/release-notes/tech_bull_21-upgrade.html.

Says that you are able to update to 2.1.0 but I could update only to 2.1.0-rc3.

After copying the patch over I edited the composer.json to request 2.1.0 but I get this error:

```
Problem 1
    - The requested package magento/product-community-edition 2.1.0 exists as magento/product-community-edition[2.1.0-rc3, 0.42.0-beta7, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3, 2.0.4, 2.0.5, 2.0.6, 2.0.7, 2.1.0-rc1, 2.1.0-rc2] but these are rejected by your constraint.
```

I have `2.1.0-rc3`. Is there anything else that I should do? The documentation mentions editing composer.lock only for EE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Till now Magento 2.1 RC3 version is released only. There is no public release of Magento 2.1

Please refer [Magento Community Edition 2.1 Release Candidate 3 Is Available for Testing!](https://community.magento.com/t5/News-Announcements/Magento-Community-Edition-2-1-Release-Candidate-3-Is-Available/m-p/39568#U39568)

The patch only fixes the issue with Magento *composer-installer* component. It is clearly mentioned on following link [Technical Bulletin - Upgrade to Magento version 2.1](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/release-notes/tech_bull_21-upgrade.html)

**Upgrade to Magento CE or EE version 2.1 without sample data**

*Upgrades to version 2.1 without sample data can fail because of an issue with the Magento composer-installer component. It doesn’t correctly detect code changes and therefore doesn’t update the cache and compiled code directories properly. As a result, fatal errors display during the upgrade.
To address the issue, you must apply a patch.*

**Update**  Magento 2.1 has been released officially,
Please read - [Introducing Magento 2.1: Content Staging & Preview, Site Search & New PayPal Features](https://community.magento.com/t5/News-Announcements/Introducing-Magento-2-1-Content-Staging-amp-Preview-Site-Search/m-p/40182#M87)

Comment: surely that's not what somebody understands from that message `More information about the patch and important instructions for command-line upgrades to Magento 2.1`

Comment: @ClaudiuCreanga Magento 2.1 has been released